# Can't access files on network drive in perl with windows 2012 r2

Tags: perl, windows-server-2012-r2, network-drive

I just recently "upgraded" my system from win 7 to win 2012 r2. Everything is running fine except 2 of my scripts that access files on a network drive. Here is my code of one script for accessing the files:

```
#! perl 
use DBI;
use strict;
use 5.010;
binmode(STDOUT , ":encoding(cp437)" );

@ARGV = glob "Z:\*_file.dat"; #calljob identifizieren
while(<>){
  #do something
}
```

When I try to run the script in an admin console with strawberry-perl it runs forever. Just like an infinite loop.

I already set a "die('test');" at the first position in the while loop but the script does not quit with the message "test" but the script "dies" when i put the die-command right before the loop.

I even tried to access the files via UNC but no change.

My sysadmin says I have all possible rights to access the network drive and the files in it. When I go to Z:\ I can see all files and copy/move/delete them.

My system preferences:

- Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter
- Strawberry Perl (64-bit) 5.18.2.2

Comment: Escape the backslash (or use single quotes: `'Z:\*_file.dat'`) or interpolation will interpret it as an escaped asterisk.

Comment: I agree. Try to print @ARGV in order to understand what's happening: `print join(" ", @ARGV);`

Comment: I just tried:   
   @ARGV = glob 'Z:\\*_calljob.dat'; 
   print join(" ", @ARGV);
   die();
With single and double quotes as well as escaped and non-escaped backslash but nothint worked and nothing was displayed.

Comment: Use forward slashes and you won't need to worry about the escaping and it will be one more step closer to being platform independent.

Comment: If i try the script on a local file it works just fine.

Comment: Just tried the forward slashes. No change. I just tested the script on a file that i copied from the network drive. It worked just fine. However I did miss to comment out the following code:

   `unlink glob "Z:\*.dat";`

But the files weren't deleted either.

Comment: Change the line to say: `@ARGV = glob "Z:\\*_file.dat" or die "$!";`.  It should either die with an error message, or if it says `Died at ...` then no files were found that match the pattern.  Also add the double `\\` to that `unlink` and put an `or die "$!";` at the end.

Comment: Done. Now it says that there is no such file or directory. But they are there. The perl interpreter runs under my username in the task manager. And like I said before I can access/modify/delete the files.

Comment: Do you get the expected file list when doing a dir command outside of perl?  i.e., what do you get from this: **dir Z:\\*_file.dat**

Comment: No! The system can't find the path.

Comment: The problem is outside of perl.  Check the status of your mapped drives via **net use**

Comment: Can you do a `dir Z:\ ` without the wildcard?  If so, I would suggest looking into using `readdir` and `grep` as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating OP's solution from a comment to an answer:</sub>

> The problems was that I started the Perl script in a console with admin rights but the local admin on this server does not have the rights to access the network drive.
> – [MrSmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3123040/mrsmith)  [Aug 19, 2014 at 8:15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328194/cant-access-files-on-network-drive-in-perl-with-windows-2012-r2#comment39576943_25328194)